# Slide a Menu on click of TabBar in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I am using 4 tabs,which are at bottom, I am using TabBarController for it, on click of each tab I load a ViewController, and it works fine, now the 4th tab is called "More", on click of moreTab I want to slide in moreVC like facebook does, and while sliding, the tabBarController should move.

Below is the image from facebook app

[image]

Below you see that their is tabBar, you can see more button, On click of it, I want to show this View.

How can we do this

Answer (score 0):

> on click of moreTab I want to slide in moreVC like Facebook does

In fact, the FB app (at least version 8.0 on iPhone) *doesn't* do that. The "More" tab in the FB app switches to a different view controller, just as all the other tab items do. You're thinking of the "friends" bar button in the upper right corner of most of the views.

I point this out only to show that Facebook isn't doing anything out of the ordinary with their tab bar. However they implement it, theirs does the same thing that `UITabBarController` does -- it manages a set of view controllers and lets the user switch between them. Trying to create a special tab that does something different from the other tabs isn't a path you should take with `UITabBarController`. If you really want a different behavior for your "More" tab, you'll need to find a third party component that implements what you want or write your own.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thanks for your comment. So do you suggest not to interfere with default UITabBarController. If yes then whether we should implement a custom UITabBarController. Or have something like what facebook is doing. I mean have button on the top which when clicked slides a different VC.

Comment: Depends on what you want. Typically, apps that have more view controllers than can fit on the 5 or 6 tabs that fit in a tab bar employ a "More..." view controller that lets you get to the ones that aren't visible. That functionality is built into UITabBarController -- you get it for free. Doing the slide-in menu that you're talking about will be extra work if you use UITabBarController, because you'll need to somehow get the tab controller to show one of your extra view controllers, one that it's not managing. If you really want that, you'll probably have to roll your own.

Comment: Presently, when user clicks on more tab, i show a VC with more options. So now i want to go with sliding menu. So which will be a good user experience?